# Select de select2 no se deja asignar un valor - Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Alguien sabe porque el select2 no se deja asignar un valor mediante javascript?, si se lo asigno con *$('#miSelect2').val(5).trigger('change.select2');*, en pantalla no hace nada, y ademas al imprimir en consola con *$('#miSelect2').val()* me imprime null. A continuacion dejo un ejemplo minimo para explicar el error:

Estoy utilizando la libreria de select2 para realizar consultar directas a base de datos con ajax. Tengo el sisguiente problema:

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura sencilla:
[image: Tabla Productos]

Se puede observar mi select2 en pantalla. La funcionalidad del mismo es seleccionar algun producto de mi base de datos, luego se indica una cantidad y al final se agrega a la tabla.

[image: Select2 con funcionalidad de añadir registros a la tabla]

Esta tabla tambien me deja editar los registros que ya tengo incluidos en ella, lo cual
funciona al dar click en el lapiz:
[image: Al oprimir el boton editar, en el select2 se coloca el "value" del registro de la tabla]

Sin embargo, esta funcionalidad no funciona siempre. El error que se encuentra es, que por javascript yo realizo la siguiente instruccion:

```
$('#miSelect2').val('5').trigger('change.select2');
```

Esta instruccion tiene como finalidad que el select2 se actualice y me muestre en pantalla la opcion con el value que se le pasa por parametro (".val(5)"). Pero esta instruccion no me esta funcionando siempre. Puse a imprimir en el log de la consola para demostrar este error:

```
console.log('Opcion del select2 antes: '+$('#miSelect2').val());
console.log('Opcion a asignar: '+opcion);
$('#miSelect2').val(opcion).trigger('change.select2');
console.log('Opcion del select2 despues: '+$('#miSelect2').val());
```

Luego ejecuto mi codigo, y elijo dos opciones de mi tabla para editar, el resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado consola]

Se puede observar que en primera parte si cumple la instruccion que le indico, la cual es asignar el valor al select2, pero en la segunda parte no lo realiza:

[image: Resultado consola coloreado]

Basicamente el error se reduce a que no esta ejecutando la instruccion de asignar el valor al select2 siempre. He podido detectar que las veces que si lo realiza es porque ese valor ya habia sido elegido mediante el select2 previamente. En cambio si le envio un valor que no ha sido seleccionado, pero que si esta dentro de las opciones del select2, este no ejecuta la instruccion. Es como si el select2 guardara en algun lugar los valores que han sido previamente seleccionados, y que solo se deja asignar esos valores por javascript, pero los demas que no han sido seleccionados, no. Alguien sabe a que se podria deber este error, o una posible solucion?

Comment: Por favor, muestra un [repro] en la pregunta misma, y las salidas en consola _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione. La respuesta está en que mi select2 funciona con ajax. La razón de que no se seleccione el valor que le estoy asignando por javascript, es precisamente porque el select2 no tiene aun las opciones listadas, el las lista cuando realizo una busqueda, y va y consulta en la base de datos con ajax. La solucion es, pasarle al select2 las opciones por medio de:

```
$('#miSelect2').select2({data:[opcion]})
```

De esta manera, si se asignara el valor que le asigne con javascript.